# Sending long string to MYSQL query, getting "//" appended and prepended which is breaking query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, where-in

I'm calling a MYSQL stored procedure from a node.js environment. The first argument of the stored procedure is a string of comma separated values that will be used in a WHERE IN clause.

I'm getting strange behavior once this string gets too long in length. The comma separated values are phone numbers, and if I include around up to 120 numbers in the string, everything works fine and the query executes without problems. This is an example of what this call looks like:

```
deleteContactByPhoneNumber3("+18884747500","+18884747501","+18884747502","+18884747503","+18884747504","+18884747505","+18884747506","+18884747507","+18884747508","+18884747509","+18884747510","+18884747511","+18884747512","+18884747513","+18884747514","+18884747515","+18884747516","+18884747517","+18884747518","+18884747519","+18884747520","+18884747521","+18884747522","+18884747523","+18884747524","+18884747525","+18884747526","+18884747527","+18884747528","+18884747529","+18884747530","+18884747531","+18884747532","+18884747533","+18884747534","+18884747535","+18884747536","+18884747537","+18884747538","+18884747539","+18884747540","+18884747541","+18884747542","+18884747543","+18884747544","+18884747545","+18884747546","+18884747547","+18884747548","+18884747549","+18884747550","+18884747551","+18884747552","+18884747553","+18884747554","+18884747555","+18884747556","+18884747557","+18884747558","+18884747559","+18884747560","+18884747561","+18884747562","+18884747563","+18884747564","+18884747565","+18884747566","+18884747567","+18884747568","+18884747569","+18884747570","+18884747571","+18884747572","+18884747573","+18884747574","+18884747575","+18884747576","+18884747577","+18884747578","+18884747579","+18884747580","+18884747581","+18884747582","+18884747583","+18884747584","+18884747888","+18884747586","+18884747587","+18884747588","+18884747589","+18884747590","+18884747591","+18884747592","+18884747593","+18884747594","+18884747595","+18884747596","+18884747597","+18884747598","+18884747599","+18884747600","+18884747601","+18884747602","+18884747603","+18884747604","+18884747605","+18884747606","+18884747607","+18884747608","+18884747609","+18884747610","+18884747611","+18884747612","+18884747613","+18884747614","+18884747615","+18884747616","+18884747617","+18884747618","+18884747619","+18884747620","+18884747621","+18884747622","+18884747623","+18884747624", 995, 1953);
```

However, once I get larger than this, the query seems to change and I get a syntax error from MYSQL. This is what the error looks like:

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"+188847)\n` +
    "\t\tAND exampleColumn1 != 'answered'\n" +
    "\t\tAND exampleColumn2 = 995' at line 8",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
```

And the new seemingly malformed query:

```
deleteContactByPhoneNumber3('\\"+18884747500\\",\\"+18884747501\\",\\"+18884747502\\",\\"+18884747503\\",\\"+18884747504\\",\\"+18884747505\\",\\"+18884747506\\",\\"+18884747507\\",\\"+18884747508\\",\\"+18884747509\\",\\"+18884747510\\",\\"+18884747511\\",\\"+18884747512\\",\\"+18884747513\\",\\"+18884747514\\",\\"+18884747515\\",\\"+18884747516\\",\\"+18884747517\\",\\"+18884747518\\",\\"+18884747519\\",\\"+18884747520\\",\\"+18884747521\\",\\"+18884747522\\",\\"+18884747523\\",\\"+18884747524\\",\\"+18884747525\\",\\"+18884747526\\",\\"+18884747527\\",\\"+18884747528\\",\\"+18884747529\\",\\"+18884747530\\",\\"+18884747531\\",\\"+18884747532\\",\\"+18884747533\\",\\"+18884747534\\",\\"+18884747535\\",\\"+18884747536\\",\\"+18884747537\\",\\"+18884747538\\",\\"+18884747539\\",\\"+18884747540\\",\\"+18884747541\\",\\"+18884747542\\",\\"+18884747543\\",\\"+18884747544\\",\\"+18884747545\\",\\"+18884747546\\",\\"+18884747547\\",\\"+18884747548\\",\\"+18884747549\\",\\"+18884747550\\",\\"+18884747551\\",\\"+18884747552\\",\\"+18884747553\\",\\"+18884747554\\",\\"+18884747555\\",\\"+18884747556\\",\\"+18884747557\\",\\"+18884747558\\",\\"+18884747559\\",\\"+18884747560\\",\\"+18884747561\\",\\"+18884747562\\",\\"+18884747563\\",\\"+18884747564\\",\\"+18884747565\\",\\"+18884747566\\",\\"+18884747567\\",\\"+18884747568\\",\\"+18884747569\\",\\"+18884747570\\",\\"+18884747571\\",\\"+18884747572\\",\\"+18884747573\\",\\"+18884747574\\",\\"+18884747575\\",\\"+18884747576\\",\\"+18884747577\\",\\"+18884747578\\",\\"+18884747579\\",\\"+18884747580\\",\\"+18884747581\\",\\"+18884747582\\",\\"+18884747583\\",\\"+18884747584\\",\\"+18884747888\\",\\"+18884747586\\",\\"+18884747587\\",\\"+18884747588\\",\\"+18884747589\\",\\"+18884747590\\",\\"+18884747591\\",\\"+18884747592\\",\\"+18884747593\\",\\"+18884747594\\",\\"+18884747595\\",\\"+18884747596\\",\\"+18884747597\\",\\"+18884747598\\",\\"+18884747599\\",\\"+18884747600\\",\\"+18884747601\\",\\"+18884747602\\",\\"+18884747603\\",\\"+18884747604\\",\\"+18884747605\\",\\"+18884747606\\",\\"+18884747607\\",\\"+18884747608\\",\\"+18884747609\\",\\"+18884747610\\",\\"+18884747611\\",\\"+18884747612\\",\\"+18884747613\\",\\"+18884747614\\",\\"+18884747615\\",\\"+18884747616\\",\\"+18884747617\\",\\"+18884747618\\",\\"+18884747619\\",\\"+18884747620\\",\\"+18884747621\\",\\"+18884747622\\",\\"+18884747623\\",\\"+18884747624\\",\\"+18884747625\\",\\"+18884747626\\",\\"+18884747627\\",\\"+18884747628\\",\\"+18884747629\\",\\"+18884747630\\",\\"+18884747631\\",\\"+18884747632\\",\\"+18884747633\\",\\"+18884747634\\",\\"+18884747635\\",\\"+18884747636\\",\\"+18884747637\\",\\"+18884747638\\",\\"+18884747639\\",\\"+18884747640\\",\\"+18884747641\\",\\"+18884747642\\",\\"+18884747643\\",\\"+18884747644\\",\\"+18884747645\\",\\"+18884747646\\",\\"+18884747647\\",\\"+18884747648\\",\\"+18884747649\\"','995','1953')
```

As you can see for some reason there are a bunch of "//" all over the place , and the string starts with a single quote instead of a double quote like in the correct query.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it? Thank you so much for any assistance.

Comment: and why didn't you post the deleteContactByPhoneNumber3 function that parses your input

Comment: I can suppose that if the procedure parameters get truncated at some point and query syntax gets invalid. 1st proposal is to check if you can control the maximum length of stored procedure input parameters length through some kind of config value. 2nd proposal is to split in multiple calls with lets say 50-60 phone numbers in a loop.

Comment: Are you using prepared statements? Most mysql drivers support a batch processing which would let you submit `N` number of queries and then actually execute them (e.g. 100 queries -> execute -> 100 more -> ...)